# Why are my `<nav>` buttons aligned to the left?

Tags: html, css

I've tried using `text-align:center` for `nav` , `ul` , `li` but they have no effect of centering the buttons in the viewport. I've also tried `nav {text-align: left;}` . Doesn't work.

CSS codes:

```
  #container {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: black;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;}

 main {
        background-color: rgb(225, 234, 234);
        display: block;
        border-radius: 2em;
        border-top: medium solid powderblue;
        border-bottom:  medium solid powderblue;
        margin-left:  0.8em;
        margin-right: 0.8em;
        padding-top: 1em;
        padding-right: 0.5em;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
        padding-left: 0.5em;}

 .equip {
          width: 100%;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;}

 h1 {
    color: powderblue;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-family: cursive,fantasy,"Times New Roman";
    font-style: italic;
    white-space: nowrap;}


 nav ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          border-radius: 2em;}

 nav ul li { 
            text-align: center;
            padding-bottom: 0.3em;
            padding-top: 0.3em;
            border-color: powderblue;
            background-color: grey;
            margin-bottom: 0.5em;
            margin-top: 0.5em;
            border-radius: 3em;}

 nav a {
        color: white;
        font-family: "Times New Roman";
        font-size: 1.3em;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-decoration: none;}


footer {
          margin-top: 1em;
          padding-bottom: 1em;
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 0.8em;
          color: white;}
```

2. HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-us">
    <head>
    <title>FFC|Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
    
    
    <div id="container">
    
    <header>
    
            <img  class="equip" src="D:\ghanesh\ghanesh\Y Combinator\Intern Summer 2019\interning Prep Course\HTML Learn\Step-by-Step Guide\Forward Fitness Club\images\fitness club logo_grey_background.jpg"
    
                    alt="Forward Fitness Club ">
    
                 <h1>
                       Forward Fitness Club
                  </h1>
    
    </header>
    
    <nav>
            <ul>
                  <li> <a href="About Us.html"> About Us </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="Classes.html"> Classes </a></li>
                  <li> <a href="About Us.html"> About Us </a></li>
                  <li> <a href="Nutrition.html"> Nutrition </a></li>
                  <li> <a href="Contact Us.html"> Contact Us </a></li>
    
            </ul>
    
    </nav>

    <main>
    
           <p>Welcome to Forward Fitness Club. Our mission is to help our clients meet their fitness <b>AND</b> nutrition goals. <br>   </p> <!--<span style="font-weight: bold"> </span>-->
    
            <h2>  FREE ONE-WEEK TRIAL MEMBERSHIP</h2>
    
    
               <a href="Contact Us.html">Call Us today to Get Started</a> <br>
    
    
                  <h3>Fitness Club Hours</h3>
    
    <p>
    
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
      <li style="text-align:left"> Monday-Thursday: 6:00am - 6:00pm</li>
      <li> Friday: 6:00am - 4:00pm</li>
      <li> Saturday: 8:00am - 6:00pm</li>
      <li> Sunday: Closed</li>
    </ul>
    
    </p>
    
    
    </main>
    
    <footer >
    
    <address>
               Copyright 2015. All Rights Reserved.<br>
    
             <a style="color:powderblue" href="ghanesh.t@gmail.com">forwardfitnessclub@gmail.com</a>
    
    </address>
    
    </footer>
    
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Image 1 : Samsung Galaxy Note 2 viewport
Image 2 : Desktop browser viewport

[image: Samsung Galaxy Note 2 browser viewport]

[image: Desktop browser viewport]

Comment: @PunithaSubramaniYoganyaaS I'm using the `<main>`  element. i tried using it as a class `.main{ }` in the css code  but doing that wouldn't display the main content  at all in the browser.

Comment: Hey @SIVARAJGHANESHALTHANASAGAR which elements exactly are you trying to center.

Comment: Yes, I viewed your code, What is your expected output? and how it is coming now? Because I tried it is coming in full view and texts are centered align.

Comment: @PunithaSubramaniYoganyaaS i'd like the buttons to be centered on the page but they aren't, in my browser. They're hugging the right margin. I'll add a screenshot image of how it looks like in my browser in the question.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me as well. Do you have your CSS linked to your HTML? In your question, you don't have any CSS for your code snippet, which is why there is no styling being applied to it.

Comment: @Nick you mean `<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">`  this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ul list has some default padding on the left. Try setting `text-align: center` **and** `padding-left: 0` for `nav ul`:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

main {
  background-color: rgb(225, 234, 234);
  display: block;
  border-radius: 2em;
  border-top: medium solid powderblue;
  border-bottom: medium solid powderblue;
  margin-left: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 0.8em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.equip {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
  color: powderblue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-family: cursive, fantasy, "Times New Roman";
  font-style: italic;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-radius: 2em;
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
  border-color: powderblue;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 3em;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 1.3em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <title>FFC|Home</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>


<body>


  <div id="container">

    <header>

      <img class="equip" src="D:\ghanesh\ghanesh\Y Combinator\Intern Summer 2019\interning Prep Course\HTML Learn\Step-by-Step Guide\Forward Fitness Club\images\fitness club logo_grey_background.jpg" alt="Forward Fitness Club ">

      <h1>
        Forward Fitness Club
      </h1>

    </header>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="About Us.html"> About Us </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="Classes.html"> Classes </a></li>
        <li> <a href="About Us.html"> About Us </a></li>
        <li> <a href="Nutrition.html"> Nutrition </a></li>
        <li> <a href="Contact Us.html"> Contact Us </a></li>

      </ul>

    </nav>

    <main>

      <p>Welcome to Forward Fitness Club. Our mission is to help our clients meet their fitness <b>AND</b> nutrition goals. <br> </p>
      <!--<span style="font-weight: bold"> </span>-->

      <h2> FREE ONE-WEEK TRIAL MEMBERSHIP</h2>


      <a href="Contact Us.html">Call Us today to Get Started</a> <br>


      <h3>Fitness Club Hours</h3>

      <p>

        <ul style="list-style-type:none">
          <li style="text-align:left"> Monday-Thursday: 6:00am - 6:00pm</li>
          <li> Friday: 6:00am - 4:00pm</li>
          <li> Saturday: 8:00am - 6:00pm</li>
          <li> Sunday: Closed</li>
        </ul>

      </p>


    </main>

    <footer>

      <address>
               Copyright 2015. All Rights Reserved.<br>
    
             <a style="color:powderblue" href="ghanesh.t@gmail.com">forwardfitnessclub@gmail.com</a>
    
    </address>

    </footer>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yeap, that did the trick,thanks! But I don't get why tho. I mean why is it padding and not margin? Because previously I tried `margin-left: 0;`  `margin-right:0;`  and it didnt work.

Comment: It's just the indent of a default list. This default could also have been created with some `margin-left` on the list items (`ul li`). But I guess padding for the list itself would make more sense because it is only 1 element. A list with 50 items with margin to the left would probably take a very little more computing time. Not really something to break your head over. Just try to remember the browser adds some default `padding-left` to every `ul`, until you change it with css.

Comment: Also,.. If you would give the ul itself a margin-left. Imagine you have a large text with some ul in between. When you would give the `ul` some `background-color`, it would not be nicely alligned with a `margin-left`. A `padding-left` fixes this. There are probably more reasons, but when you think about it, it makes more sence to have a default left padding on a list, then it would to have a left margin. An ul list also has some default margin. But that would be top and bottom. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It works if you put it as  `nav {  text-align: center;}`

```css
 #container {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: black;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;}

 main {
        background-color: rgb(225, 234, 234);
        display: block;
        border-radius: 2em;
        border-top: medium solid powderblue;
        border-bottom:  medium solid powderblue;
        margin-left:  0.8em;
        margin-right: 0.8em;
        padding-top: 1em;
        padding-right: 0.5em;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
        padding-left: 0.5em;}

 .equip {
          width: 100%;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;}

 h1 {
    color: powderblue;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    font-family: cursive,fantasy,"Times New Roman";
    font-style: italic;
    white-space: nowrap;}


 nav ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          border-radius: 2em;}
          
          nav {  text-align: center;}
         main{  text-align: center;}
         address{  text-align: center;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-us">
    <head>
    <title>FFC|Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
    
    
    <div id="container">
    
    <header>
    
            <img  class="equip" src="D:\ghanesh\ghanesh\Y Combinator\Intern Summer 2019\interning Prep Course\HTML Learn\Step-by-Step Guide\Forward Fitness Club\images\fitness club logo_grey_background.jpg"
    
                    alt="Forward Fitness Club ">
    
                 <h1>
                       Forward Fitness Club
                  </h1>
    
    </header>
    
    <nav>
            <ul>
                  <li> <a href="About Us.html"> About Us </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="Classes.html"> Classes </a></li>
                  <li> <a href="About Us.html"> About Us </a></li>
                  <li> <a href="Nutrition.html"> Nutrition </a></li>
                  <li> <a href="Contact Us.html"> Contact Us </a></li>
    
            </ul>
    
    </nav>

    <main>
    
           <p>Welcome to Forward Fitness Club. Our mission is to help our clients meet their fitness <b>AND</b> nutrition goals. <br>   </p> <!--<span style="font-weight: bold"> </span>-->
    
            <h2>  FREE ONE-WEEK TRIAL MEMBERSHIP</h2>
    
    
               <a href="Contact Us.html">Call Us today to Get Started</a> <br>
    
    
                  <h3>Fitness Club Hours</h3>
    
    <p>
    
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
      <li style="text-align:center"> Monday-Thursday: 6:00am - 6:00pm</li>
      <li> Friday: 6:00am - 4:00pm</li>
      <li> Saturday: 8:00am - 6:00pm</li>
      <li> Sunday: Closed</li>
    </ul>
    
    </p>
    
    
    </main>
    
    <footer >
    
    <address>
               Copyright 2015. All Rights Reserved.<br>
    
             <a style="color:powderblue" href="ghanesh.t@gmail.com">forwardfitnessclub@gmail.com</a>
    
    </address>
    
    </footer>
    
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i tried it but it still wouldn't align the buttons at the center.

Comment: @SIVARAJGHANESHALTHANASAGAR   You can run it here, everything is center now.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes browser apply the default user stylesheet, If you missing the common styles to mention in your class.

Example I given[image]

[image]

So my solution is, try to add padding in your code

```
padding: 0px
```